# Unable to create Podfile because 'plist file at path doesn't exist'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

Running command `pod init .` returns:

> [!] The plist file at path
>   `/Users/admin/Desktop/TestProject/project.pbxproj` doesn't exist.

I'm running the command from the 'Test Project' folder. To get to the .plist file: `TestProject > TestProject > Info.plist`.

I have the path to the plist file set up in my build settings like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Is cocoapod properly installed in your system?

Comment: what's going on I have the same problem did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 13):

Because the command is not `pod init .` it's `pod init`

[CocaoPods Guide Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfGHP.png)

That period is just the end of the sentence in cocoapod's guide. https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

This just got me too, simple typo :)